# Inserting data in a column avoiding duplicates

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Lets say i have a query which is fetching col1 after joining multiple tables. I want to insert values of that col1 in a table which is on remote db i.e. i would be using dblink to do that.

Now that col1 would be fetched from 4-5 different db's. There is chances that a value1 fetch from db1 would b in db2 as well. How can i avoid duplicates ?

In my remote db, I have created col1 a primary key. so when inserting, an error would be thrown if there is a duplicate key, end result failing rest of the process. Which i don't want to. I was thiking about 2 approaches

1. Write a PLSQL script, For each value, determine if value already exists or not. If it doesn't then insert.
2. Write a PLSQL script and insert and catch the duplicate key exception. The exception would be ignore and it will keep inserting (it doesn't sound that good).

Which approach would you prefer? Is there anything else i can do ?

Comment: Does each of the 4-5 different databases have it's own procedure to select data and insert remotely. Or, are you selecting from 4-5 databases in one SQL statement and then inserting remotely? Or, does your remote database with the table have a single `INSERT...SELECT DISTINCT...FROM table@remotedb1, table@remotedb2` that fetches from all remote databases?

Comment: every db would have their own script inserting into one common db.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the MERGE statement and WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT.

The same merger could also update but it doesn't have to, just leave the update part out.

Comment: can the merge statement be used as BULK merge ? The reason i would be using insert statement is `FORALL` bulk insert.

Comment: Instead of using `FORALL` you can declare object type, then table of that type and after that cast your collection as 'table(your_collection)' and fit to `MERGE` syntax.

Comment: can you link me to some example ?

Answer (score 1):

The different databases can have duplicate primary keys but that doesn't mean the records are duplicates.  The actual data may be different in each case.  Or the records may represent the same real world thing but at different statuses,  Don't know, you haven't provided enough explanation.

The point is, you need much more analysis of why duplicate records can exist and probably a more sophisticated approach to handling collisions.  Do you need to take all records (in which case you need a synthetic key)?  Or do you take only one instance (so how do you decide precedence)?  Other scenarios may exist.

In any case, MERGE or PL/SQL loops are likely to be too crude a solution.

Comment: The original application replicate primary key (col1) across multiple db's for different reasons. I have to flag that primary key (col1) on specific condigion. DB1 might have some data which isn't enough to flag the col1 but DB2 might have some data to flag it and same goes for DB3 and DB4. So while flagging, DB1 wouldn't result in any insertion. But DB2 would result in insertion. When DB3 comes, it would result in failure since the flag mechanism has already flagged the pk in DB2.

Answer (score 1):

First off, I would suggest that your target database drive all of these inserts because inserting/updating across a database link can create some locking issues and further complicate things especially with multiple databases attempting to access and perform DML on the same table.  However if that isn't possible the solutions below will work.

I would fix your primary key problem by including a table look-up on the target table for each row.

```
INSERT INTO customer@dblink.oracle.com cust
(emp_name,
 emp_id)
VALUES
(SELECT 
    cust.employee_name, 
    cust.employee_id --primary_key
FROM
    source_table st
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 1 
   FROM customer@dblink.oracle.com cust
   WHERE cust.employee_id = st.emp_id));
```

Again, I would not recommend DML transactions across database links unless absolutely necessary as you can sometimes have weird locking behavior.

A PL/SQL procedure or anonymous PL/SQL block could be used to create a bulk processing solution as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE send_unique_data
AS
  TYPE tab_cust IS TABLE OF customer@dblink.oracle.com%ROWTYPE
     INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  t_records   tab_cust;

BEGIN
    SELECT 
      cust.employee_name, 
      cust.employee_id --primary_key
    BULK COLLECT
    INTO t_records
    FROM source_table;

    FORALL i IN t_records.FIRST...t_records.LAST SAVE EXCEPTIONS
        INSERT INTO customer@dblink.oracle.com
        VALUES t_records(i);
END send_unique_data;
```

You can also call the system SQL%BULKEXCEPTIONS collection in case you want to do anything with the records that threw exceptions (such as unique_constraint violations).  Be warned that this solution will cause the target table to suffers from performance issues if there are lots of duplicate data attempting to be inserted.